# Duplicate choice values in .setChoices error -

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I get the "cannot have duplicate choice values" in.setChoices
I am trying to reproduce a successful tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKliSlFZfV4 but I am unable to pass thru this error in running the script. This is to make a quiz from sheets for classroom use. Thank you for your help.

Here is the code:

function popForm() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

// var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

// Read the sheet data into 3 arrays.  Would be better practice (faster performance) to read all into 1 array and divide as needed).

var myQuestions = sheet.getRange(1,1,numberRows,1).getValues();

var myAnswers = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,1).getValues();

var myGuesses = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,5).getValues();

// Shuffle the 5 choices horizontally.  This script only works with Questions in col A, correct Answer in col B, and false choices in col C thru F.

var myShuffled = myGuesses.map(shuffleEachRow);

Logger.log(myShuffled);

Logger.log(myAnswers);

// Create the form as a quiz.  The resulting form's "Quiz options" are different from a manually created quiz.  Be aware (and change manually if needed!

var form = FormApp.create('States and Capitals Quiz');

form.setIsQuiz(true);

// Write out each multiple choice question to the form.

for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){

```
if (myShuffled[i][0] == myAnswers[i][0]) {

  var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

  .setPoints(1)
```

//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR ORIGINATES IN setChoices

```
  .setChoices([

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0],true),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])

  ]);

}

else if (myShuffled[i][1] == myAnswers[i][0]) {

  var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

  .setPoints(1)

  .setChoices([

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1],true),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])

  ]);

}

else if (myShuffled[i][2] == myAnswers[i][0]) {

  var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

  .setPoints(1)

  .setChoices([

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2],true),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])

  ]);

}

else if (myShuffled[i][3] == myAnswers[i][0]) {

  var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

  .setPoints(1)

  .setChoices([

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3],true),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])

  ]);

}

else {

  var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

  .setPoints(1)

  .setChoices([

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),

    addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4],true)

  ]);

}
```

}

}

// This function, called by popForm, shuffles the 5 choices.

function shuffleEachRow(array) {

var i, j, temp;

for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

```
j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));

temp = array[i];

array[i] = array[j];

array[j] = temp;
```

}

return array;

}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to solve the specific problem with .setChoices in script - thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. In sheets, I had literally some duplicate values (in this case, state capital names were duplicated from the random function).